# IEnumerable <SelectListItem> - Condition for each item in IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable, selectlistitem

I'm using MVC Razor's @Html.DropDownList to generate dropdown list.

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
         {
             Value = c.ID,
             Text = c.Name 
         });
        ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

This TABLE has one more field which determines activity of each item in the table.

If I use following code I get that activity field included after c.Name

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
         {
             Value = c.ID,
             Text = c.Name + " - " + c.Activity 
         });
        ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

My problem is that that field has only one character which determines it's activity. A - Active, N - Not active. 
I would like to show custom text "Not Active" for those items in SelectListItem  that have value "N". Something like...

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
         {
             Value = c.ID,
             Text = c.Name + " - " + IF C.ACTIVITY IS "N", THEN PRINT "NOT ACTIVE" 
         });
        ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

I hope someone can help me achieve something like this

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 1

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 2

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 3

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 4

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 5 - NOT ACTIVE

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 6 - NOT ACTIVE

DROPDOWN LIST ITEM 7 - NOT ACTIVE

Answer (score 2):

I don't promote the use of `ViewBag`, but this should work:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
     {
         Value = c.ID,
         Text = c.Name + (c.ACTIVITY == "N" ? " - NOT ACTIVE" : string.empty)
     });
    ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [conditional operator - ?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
.Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = c.ID,
    Text = c.Name + (c.Activity == "N" ? " - NOT ACTIVE" : "")
});
ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

Comment: You have the condition backwards. `(c.Activity == "N" ? " - NOT ACTIVE" : "")`

Comment: You should mark Win's answer as accepted if it fixed or helped to fix your issue. That way this won't continue to show up on the list of unanswered questions (and Win gets the credit he's due for answering).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = c.ID,
                 Text = c.Name + (c.Activity == "N") ? " - Not Active " : "";
             });
            ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR;
```

Comment: IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cSfRR = db.TABLE.Where(m => m.cRoleName == dbrole)
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = c.ID,
                 Text = c.Name + (c.Activity == "N" ? " - Not Active " : "");
             });
            ViewBag.cSfRR = cSfRR; - Just parenthesis should close at the end